# Can I use Grep or Grepl to return instances of two capital letters together in text?

Tags: r

I'm interested to pull out instances where initials are used in my text data, as they are almost always two capital letters, is there a simple way to look for this text pattern using Grep in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to match two upper case letters from the start (`^`) of the string, use `grepl` on the column concerned to return a logical expression within `subset` to subset the rows

```
subset(df1, grepl("^[A-Z]{2}", col1))
```